# how can i publish apk with same package name but different version code and version name

Tags: android, google-play

I am building an android application. And signed epic through eclipse (export signed application package) and then zip align the project.after complete all step i publish apk on android market.application was published.But now i make some changes in my application and publish again with same package but different version code and version name but an error occurred during uploading apk on play store account

```
   Upload failed

  You need to use a different package name because "org.dan.activity" is already used by 
  one of your other applications.
```

I make change in manifest from

```
            android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0"
```

In upgraded app

```
            android:versionCode="2"
        android:versionName="1.1"
```

please provide some solution how can i publish apk with same package name but different version code and version name

Comment: if it is the same package name but different version code and name then it should be an update to your already published app

Comment: yes sir it is update my app but i am not able to upload again on google play

Comment: Once you've published the app in Google Play, you cannot published the same version of the app again. It has to be a new version. That's how Google Play works.

Comment: Sir i change version no and version code from version code=1 to version code =2 and version name 1.0 to version name= 1.1 but apk was not upload how can i publish same app updated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this link regarding how to update an existing app on Google Play: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Basically:

1. Log into your console at http://play.google.com/apps/publish
2. You should see a list of all of your apps on Google Play. If you don't select "All Apps" in the left-hand navigation
3. Click on the application. This should take you to a site that has a URL similar to https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=LONG_NUMBER#MarketListingPlace:p=PACKAGE_NAME_OF_YOUR_APPLICATION
4. Next to the navigation on the left-hand-side, there is a secondary navigation that has a button labeled "APK". Click it.
5. Now you can should be able to see a button labeled "upload to new APK".

Find two images here, that have markings where you need to click:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1zZR.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9tcX.png

Answer (score 0):

Creating new app version in Google Play Store:

1. Log into your console at http://play.google.com/apps/publish
2. You should see a list of all of your apps on Google Play. If you don't, THEN select "All Apps" in the left-hand navigation
3. Click on the application. This should take you to a site that has a URL similar to `https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=LONG_NUMBER#MarketListingPlace:p=PACKAGE_NAME_OF_YOUR_APPLICATION`
4. Next to the navigation on the left-hand-side, there is a secondary navigation that has a button labeled "APK". Click it.
5. Now you  should be able to see a button labeled "upload to new APK".
   Click on it. Then upload your app with the same package name, and signed with the same keystore. Then, version code should be one integer higher.  Also, version number should be higher than the previous version number.

Note: if the store listing of your app requires any correction, you will have to update it with all the info it requires. if not, the botton label “upload new apk” will be blank